# Web Crawler not working with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parser

I'm having issues with a simple web crawler, when I run the following script, it is not iterating through the sites and it does not give me any results.

This is what I get:

```
1 Visiting: https://www.mongodb.com/
Word never found

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any tips as why this is not working correctly? I'm using the following example (http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-in-under-50-lines-of-python-code/)

Here is the code:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib import parse

class LinkParser(HTMLParser):
    # This is a function that HTMLParser normally has
    # but we are adding some functionality to it

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
      """  We are looking for the begining of a link.
        Links normally look
        like <a href="www.someurl.com"></a> """
      if tag == 'a':
          for (key,value) in attrs:
              if key == 'href':
              # We are grabbing the new URL. We are also adding the
              # base URL to it. For example:
              # www.netinstructions.com is the base and
              # somepage.html is the new URL (a relative URL)
              #
              # We combine a relative URL with the base URL to create
              # an absolute URL like:
              # www.netinstructions.com/somepage.html
                 newUrl = parse.urljoin(self.baseUrl, value)
              # And add it to our colection of links:
                 self.links = self.links + [newUrl]

    def getLinks(self, url):
        self.links = []
        # Remember the base URL which will be important when creating
        # absolute URLs
        self.baseUrl = url
        # Use the urlopen function from the standard Python 3 library
        response = urlopen(url)
        # Make sure that we are looking at HTML and not other things that
        # are floating around on the internet (such as
        # JavaScript files, CSS, or .PDFs for example)
        if response.getheader('Content-Type') == 'text/html':
            htmlBytes = response.read()
            # Note that feed() handles Strings well, but not bytes
            # (A change from Python 2.x to Python 3.x)
            htmlString = htmlBytes.decode("utf-8")
            self.feed(htmlString)
            return htmlString, self.links
        else:
            return "", []

# And finally here is our spider. It takes in an URL, a word to find,
# and the number of pages to search through before giving up
def spider(url, word, maxPages):
    pagesToVisit = [url]
    numberVisited = 0
    foundWord = False
    # The main loop. Create a LinkParser and get all the links on the page.
    # Also search the page for the word or string
    # In our getLinks function we return the web page
    # (this is useful for searching for the word)
    # and we return a set of links from that web page
    # (this is useful for where to go next)
    while numberVisited < maxPages and pagesToVisit != [] and not foundWord:
        numberVisited = numberVisited +1
        # Start from the beginning of our collection of pages to visit:
        url = pagesToVisit[0]
        pagesToVisit = pagesToVisit[1:]
        try:
            print(numberVisited, "Visiting:", url)
            parser = LinkParser()
            data, links = parser.getLinks(url)
            if data.find(word)>-1:
                foundWord = True
                # Add the pages that we visited to the end of our collection
                # of pages to visit:
                pagesToVisit = pagesToVisit + links
                print(" **Success!**")
        except:
            print(" **Failed!**")
    if foundWord:
        print("The word", word, "was found at", url)
    else:
        print("Word never found")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spider("https://www.mongodb.com/", "MongoDB" ,400)
```

Comment: It probably has something to do with response.getheader('Content-Type') == 'text/html' not executing. urlopen does not seem to have a method called getheader(). The [info() method does however, seem to retrieve header information](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

Comment: @Fruitspunchsamurai It does, but in this case it's not returning just `'text/html'`, but `'text/html; charset=utf-8'`. That's the source of the issue. A little debugging goes a long way!

Comment: I see my error, I looked urllib, not urllib2, which is what urllib.request is

Comment: You better use requests library and beautiful soup. It will save you a lot of time and headaches.

Comment: When I run spider("http://www.dreamhost.com", "dream", 200) it does find the word, And I get **Success!**
The word dream was found at http://www.dreamhost.com --- However, it still not iterating through the pages, that is my main problem :/

Comment: pagesToVisit = pagesToVisit + links does not add anything at the moment, meaning it is = []. Your program can't iterate if you don't have anything to iterate through.

Comment: Ohhh, You are right. I see my issue. I just checked and the pagesToVisit is [] , so no links, is there an easy way to solve this then?

Comment: First off, take @glibdud advice and have an or statement for the charset being part of the content type, this will let you find 'word'.

Comment: The code is strange. Even if you fix the Content-Type header issue, it doesn't seem right. It will only add the new links to the list if it finds the word it's looking for on the page, but then once it finds it, it stops looping.

Comment: @glibdud Yes, the link OP provided seems to scan through all the links and check for 'word'.

Answer (score 0):

First, edit the content-type checker line to:

```
if response.getheader('Content-Type') == 'text/html; charset=utf-8':
```

as suggested by @glibdud.

If you would like your program to check all links until maxPages is reached or pagesTovisit = [], simply remove the and condition for found word on the line:

```
while numberVisited < maxPages and pagesToVisit != [] and not foundWord:
```

to:

```
while numberVisited < maxPages and pagesToVisit != []:
```